# JUnit Test runs on Local but not on Jenkins

Tags: java, spring, maven, jenkins

I've got strange error with Jenkins.

The Jenkins server is on the same computer as the local test, but here is what I've got :

When I run 4 tests about a class named CarStatusDao on Local (by runnning the cmd Windows), here in the output :

```
Running net.****.****.dao.carstatus.CarStatusDaoTest

Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.032 sec
```

The tests run without any problem.

When I execute the exact same code, but on Jenkins (who get the exact same code from a SVN):

```
Running net.****.****.dao.carstatus.CarStatusDaoTest

2015-07-31 15:29:21,497 ERROR [org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager] - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener 
[org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@c316b9] to prepare test instance [net.****.****.dao.carstatus.CarStatusDaoTest@1121079]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'net.****.****.dao.carstatus.CarStatusDaoTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: net.****.****.dao.CarStatusDao net.****.****.dao.carstatus.CarStatusDaoTest.carStatusDAO; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No matching bean of type [net.****.****.dao.CarStatusDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)} 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:379)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75) 
    at [...]

Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 4, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.011 sec <<< FAILURE!
```

From theses  logs, the important part is :

```
Error creating bean with name 'net.****.****.dao.carstatus.CarStatusDaoTest': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Could not autowire field: net.****.****.dao.CarStatusDao net.****.****.dao.carstatus.CarStatusDaoTest.carStatusDAO;
```

So basically, in local Maven is able to `autowired` my attribute `carStatusDAO` in the class `CarStatusDaoTest`, but when I run it on Jenkins, it is not able... :/

I don't understand why such differents behaviors whereas the Maven is the same and the code is the same also.... :/

I assume it's a **classpath problem**, because that's the only different thing :/

but I don't know how to fix it.

For the context, here is my /META-INF/spring/carfleet-dao-test-context.xml :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="net.****.****" />

<jd:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL">
    <jd:script location="classpath:sql/hsql-schema.sql" />
    <jd:script location="classpath:sql/test-data.sql" />
</jd:embedded-database>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="testunit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" >
        <list>
            <value>net.****.****.domain</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

Here is the definition of my class CarStatusDaoTest :

```
public class CarStatusDaoTest extends AbstractDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    CarStatusDao carStatusDAO;

    @Test
    public void getCurrentStatusOfCarTesting() {

        carStatus = carStatusDAO.getCurrentStatusOfCar(-1L);
        assertEquals(carStatus, null);
    }

    [...]
}
```

And here is the Mother Class for all my tests :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath*:/META-INF/spring/carfleet-dao-test-context.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
public class AbstractDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private EntityFactory entityFactory;

    public EntityFactory getEntityFactory() {
        return entityFactory;
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldEntityFactoryBeNotNull() {

        assertNotNull(entityFactory);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Best Regards.

**EDIT**

Here is the Maven configuration displayed on Jenkins :

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T13:57:37+02:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Maven
Java version: 1.7.0_80-ea, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

And here is the result of mvn -v in the Windows console :

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T13:57:37+02:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Maven
Java version: 1.7.0_80-ea, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

Comment: When you say local, it is on eclipse or on the console?

Comment: On the Windows console, with the command :  

mvn -e -P prod clean package.

Which is the exact command in Jenkins

Comment: What about the java version of the two enviroment? I've had some problems with different versions. Just trying to eliminate the possibilities.

Comment: If that is the only error you can in the logs I don't expect it to be the classpath since then you should get reasons for not being able to autowire being NoClassDefFoundError or similar. When you say "when I run it on Jenkins" what exactly do you run? Building a normal maven build? Deploying it somewhere?

Comment: I just edit, and I put the Maven configuration displayed by Jenkins, and displayed by mvn -v

Comment: @nesohc : Jenkins is executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Users\Valentin\.jenkins\workspace\Project\pom.xml -e -P prod clean package.

Comment: have you checked your settings.xml files to check your repositories? 
What I mean with that is for example if you have libs it could be that you are running in jenkins towards an older version of that lib. Since what it more or less says is that, you have not created a bean of the type CarStatusDao. So the question is how do your CarStatusDao look like, is that within the same jar file as you are building? If not you can have two different repository which each have that jar but containing different things. I assume you have the @Repository annotation in CarStatusDao and component scan it?

Comment: Make sure you have added CarStatusDaoImpl to svn and checked that in. I have a different IntelliJ skin but normally it has a different colour if you have not checked in the class or not added it to svn. And if you haven't added it you should get this effect.

Comment: *---* It was just that, TortoiseSVN who didn't add everything to my commit ... :o It's building now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just an issue that the class `CarStatusDaoImpl` was not commited...

With every class commited on the SVN, Jenkins is getting them and :

```
Running net.****.****.dao.carstatus.CarStatusDaoTest

Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.036 sec
```

Is appearing on Jenkins ! Thanks @[nesohc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1785022/nesohc) !

Answer (score 0):

i get this bean related error when jenkins job had browserCapabilties mentioned while run local. ,after deleting browserCapbilties and run the job local did not throw this error and test passed
[image]